# Signing digital Family information form for Canadian Visa

Tags: visas, canada

I am filling out the Family information form for Canadian Visa. At the end of every section, the form requires me to put my signature. But the problem is that the place for signature is inactive and therefore, I am not able to put my signature or name on it.

My question is, is it necessary to put signature in the Family information form when applying for Canadian visa online. If yes, then how can I do it?

Comment: Is the signature field active on other pages ? Do you submit the entire application online or do you save it to a pdf then upload it ?

Comment: It is a PDF file. I have to fill it and upload it. And the signature field is not active on other application forms as well.

Comment: you can sign it by hand and upload after scanning. Tedious, but it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've filled in the PDF, you can print it, sign it by hand, scan it then upload it. It's tedious, but does what you want

Answer (score 0):

Adobe DC has the ability to put an e-signature on the document. It's just a resizable image of your name with several font choices (cursive and printed variants) that you can resize to fit the signature line. You may need the paid Pro version to do this, I am not certain. It's what I do as I don't own a printer and don't want to print/scan at work.

Answer (score 0):

Preview on a Mac will let you record a picture of your signature with the camera (or many versions of the signature if you don't want than to all be identical) that you can subsequently resize and place on the page. You can also choose the color of the "ink" if you want.