# Does one need to sign form 5707e for Canadian's visitor visa online application?

Tags: visas, canada, paperwork, tourist-visas, applications

If I'm applying to a Canadian visitor visa online, do I need to sign form 5707e? There are fields for signature, but I can't write my name in as the form is protected. Some sources [claim](https://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/threads/imm5707e-form.398101/#post-4978623) that no signature is necessary, but I don't see any official proof of this.  Other sources say that one actually has to print the form out, sign, and then scan and upload it.

The main form, 5257e, once filled out and validated through Adobe Reader, explicitly says that no signature is necessary (even though there is a field for a signature) if applying online. But there is no "validate" button for form 5707e, that's why it's not quite clear whether I have to print it out, sign, and then scan.

After typing my question I found [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49109/signing-digital-family-information-form-for-canadian-visa), but the accepted answer doesn't provide any source that one should actually sign the form by hand and hence I'm not sure whether the answer is credible. As I pointed out, there is information contradicting that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not physically sign or scan any form, and everything went through well.

Comment: When did this occur?

Comment: @David About a month ago.